# Typescript generic class with parameterless constructor

Tags: typescript

consider the following class:

```
class Gen<Type> {
  lst1 :Type[];
  lst2 :Type[];
  constructor() {
    this.lst1 = [];
    this.lst2 = [];
  }
  add1(a:Type){
    console.log(typeof a);
    this.lst1[0]=a;
  }
  add2(a:Type){
    console.log(typeof a);
    this.lst2[0]=a;
  }
}
 
const b = new Gen();
b.add1("string");
console.log(b.lst1);
b.add2(1);
console.log(b.lst2);
```

**Output**

```
[LOG]: "string"  
[LOG]: ["string"]
[LOG]: "number"
[LOG]: [1]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7APAFQJ4Ad4D5oG8AoaaECAFwEZoAuDbAbQF0BuY0igJlvvmbZLAA9ogoAnAK7ByQsQAoAlAXYlyACwCWEAHRkq0ALzR+K6Oq26uh463YBfdmAAmTynLB0s8BURKCREEIg8LpCAOZy5F5CAGbQYAoCfuY6epQMAAxMBmBJDiTOTpzuntg+psKiQSEg4ZHRcQlJqpqpXJnZufaE+YSVFNAARtaI8ADucEiKbIPahW4AROIaiGELiX0B1aERs2kbs4XFlBv927W7luSciUA)

It does not give errors and runs.
Note that the constructor is parameterless.
Is there any enforcement here on what `Type` can be? Is `Type` in this case equivalent to the `any` type?

**Edit:**
We can explicitly specify the Type as mentioned in [@Alex Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne)'s comment

`` const b = new Gen<string>(); // explicitly set `Type` ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unspecified, and unconstrained, generic type parameters assume a type of `unknown`.

In fact, unconstrained generic parameters are implicitly constrained by `unknown`.

```
// Types A and B are 100% equivalent.
type A<T> = T
type B<T extends unknown> = T
```

---

If you hover over the `b` from your code in your IDE (or the Typescript playground) you should see the full type of that value. In this case you would see:

```
const b = new Gen(); // Gen<unknown>
```

`unknown` can accept any value, but in order to use it, you have to do runtime tests to figure out what it is.

For example:

```
const b = new Gen(); // Gen<unknown>
b.add1("hello, world!");
const fromLst1 = b.lst1[0] // unknown

fromLst1.toUpperCase() // type error
if (typeof fromLst1 === 'string') fromLst1.toUpperCase() // fine
```

---

> Is there any enforcement here on what `Type` can be? Is `Type` in this case equivalent to the any type?

`unknown` has type safety because you must prove the value is a certain type before Typescript will let you use it as that type. The `any` type lets you use the value as anything without that testing.

So this is technically type safe because you can't do anything inherently unsafe with `unknown`.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7APAFQJ4Ad4D5oG8AoaaECAFwEZoAuDbAbQF0BuY0igJlvvmbfbAA9ogoAnAK7ByQsQAoAlAXYlyACwCWEAHRkq0ALzR+K6Oq26uh463YBfduzAATZ5Tlg6WeAqIkSwqJCIPC6QgDmcuTeQgBm0GAKbP5mmjp6lAwADEzWYMnQDiROrpweXti+poEQwaEgEVEx8YkFqmmW5JzZuUb59oRFhDXk0ABG1ojwAO5wSIpsAPSLKQB6APyEhGPaLm5yAERq8CANADTQ07IgzgCEB0nDIhTQsWJCALYAMhTURjsZHpbN6fH5UbQyACqmGwYgAwpB4IpoMtoPAxO8xIQNPEmtg4q93t9foYDEYAOTiDSIcLkpQg4ngqEw9EIiBIpSoq5iADWEC2hCAA)

---

> In C# for example, we do not need constructor parameters to define T in something like class Gen{}. Is Typescript forcing the use of synthetic parameters for the sake of more specifically defining Type?

You can always explicitly pass in your own type, which is probably expected if the type can't be inferred from an argument. Otherwise you can't do much with the values it collects.

For example:

```
const b = new Gen<string>(); // explicitly set `Type`

b.add("hello, world!");
b.add(123); // error

b.lst1[0].toUpperCase() // works
```

Comment: In C# for example, we do not need constructor parameters to define `T` in something like `class Gen<T>{}`. Is Typescript forcing the use of synthetic parameters for the sake of more specifically defining `Type`?

Comment: You can always explicitly pass in your own type, which is probably expected if the type can't be inferred from an argument. Otherwise you can't do much with the values it collects. For example: https://tsplay.dev/WKy0GN

Comment: I did not know I could pass specify the Type explicitly like that! It is not mentioned in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#generic-classes). That is the usage familiar to me. Thanks

Comment: It is mentioned just above that, though in the "Generic Types" section. With examples like `let myIdentity: GenericIdentityFn<number> = identity;`. That fact this happens to be a generic class doesn't change any of that fundamentally. You can _always_ pass a type to use to any generic parameter, and it will be always be used over anything that might have been inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
type newtype = string;

class Gen<type extends newtype> {
  lst1 :type[];
  lst2 :type[];
  constructor() {
    this.lst1 = [];
    this.lst2 = [];
  }
  add1(a:type){
    console.log(typeof a);
    this.lst1[0]=a;
  }
  add2(a:type){
    console.log(typeof a);
    this.lst2[0]=a;
  }
}

const b = new Gen();
b.add1('string');
console.log(b.lst1);
b.add2(1);
console.log(b.lst2);
```

This would help you restrict the type to just string and you can add other types to newtype like this:

type newtype = string | number | etc;